# jasypt message integrity

Tags: encryption, authentication, java

I've been looking into ways to encrypt an authentication token that I need to pass from one site to another. Things i have learned so far are

- use a high level library.
- don't use ECB
- use a HMAC to provide message integrity.
- encrypt then hash

So in my search for such a easy to use high level open source java library I bumped into [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org). But i have been digging a bit through the code and it seems not to use any HMAC at all. So i'm wondering if i shouldn't use this library and which alternatives are adequate. I prefer a java-only solution ( no C bindings ).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/). This is a cryptography toolkit which once was developed by Google. It has Java, Python and C++ implementations. As far as I'm aware Keyczar was thoroughly tested. During that testing one timing attack was found and fixed. However this was the only case so far and I would consider it a fairly good bet.

The [PDF file](http://keyczar.googlecode.com/files/keyczar05b.pdf) in chapter 8 provides some better information about HMAC. And if you look at the question »[Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/320)« at crypto.SE you get a deeper answer to the Encrypt-then-MAC case.

Answer (score 0):

I think [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) would be an option that you can look into. I have personally used it and has lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using an authenticated encryption mode (e.g., GCM, EAX) instead of worrying about when you should compute your HMAC. BouncyCastle includes several options:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/AEADBlockCipher.html

(You might not have any associated data in your case; that's OK.)